# Abrir documento do Google Drive e aplicar filtros

Tags: javascript, google, google-sheets

Olá,

comecei a usar o Google Drive para ser mais fácil partilhar documentos entre os diversos departamentos da empresa mas não sei como se criam "Macros".

Gostava de ter um ficheiro **MENU** onde constem os diversos departamentos e que através de link abram o mesmo ficheiro Geral mas com filtros consoante o departamento que o abriu.

**Exemplo:**
O Departamento Comercial abre o **MENU** e carrega no botão **Comercial** e o **Ficheiro Geral** é aberto. (Até aqui já consegui fazer e funciona)

```
//Abrir Ficheiro
function AbrirComercial() {
var page =
 '<script>window.open("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/xxxxxxxxx"); google.script.host.close()</script>';

var interface = HtmlService
.createHtmlOutput(page)
.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
.setWidth(1)
.setHeight(1);   
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(interface, 'Abrindo... ');
}
```

O que não estou a conseguir é executar os filtros após a abertura do Ficheiro Geral.

Se abrir o ficheiro e executar função a função tudo corre bem porém o que pretendo é que depois de abrir o Ficheiro Geral os seguintes filtros sejam aplicados.

```
//Filtrar Comercial
{ var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('C4').activate();
var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
.setHiddenValues(['', 'Consumiveis', 'Direcção Financeira', 'Direcção Geral', 'Electricidade', 'Expansão', 'Financeiro', 'Limpeza', 'Manutenção', 'Manutenção Armazém', 'Manutenção Armazéns', 'Operações', 'Patrimonio', 'Procurement', 'Responsabilidade Técnica', 'RH', 'Segurança', 'Serviços Centrais'])
.build();
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(3, criteria);

 //Filtro Activos  
spreadsheet.getRange('J4').activate();
var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
.setHiddenValues(['#N/D', 'Desactivo'])
.build();
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(10, criteria);  
};
```

Há alguma forma de para a execução de script enquanto a página é carregada para só depois executar os filtros?

Obrigado.